# object value coming undefined in node controller function

Tags: node.js, angular

I've created a contact form with angular 7 and integrated it with nodemailer so that upon submitting the form the details of the form should be submitted to an specified email. The view is working fine and passing the values perfectly, but when the values are sent to the node backend it's coming as undefined as a result of which the email is coming but values are written as undefined. Please have a look at the code below:

Node Controller function:

```
app.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/blogs'+'/send/mail', (req, res) => {

    let user = {
                name: req.body.name,email: req.body.email,phone: req.body.phone,message: req.body.message}
console.log(user.name)    //values in this user object is coming undefined
console.log(req.body)
    //nodemailer setup
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'example@gmail.com',
      pass: 'password'
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'example@gmail.com',
    to: 'example@gmail.com',
    subject: 'A new lead has Arrived!',
    html: `<p>Name: ${user.name}</p>
           <p>Email: ${user.email}</p>
           <p>Phone: ${user.phone}</p>
           <p>Message: ${user.message}</p>`
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
});
```

Angular .ts file:

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  contactForm: FormGroup;
  public formName: string;
  public formEmail: string;
  public formPhone: number;
  public formMessage: string;
  constructor(private router: Router, private blogpostService: BlogpostService, 
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private toastr: ToastrManager) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      formName: ['', Validators.required],formEmail: ['', Validators.required],formPhone: ['', Validators.required],formMessage: ['']})}
  public contact() {
    const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('name', this.contactForm.get('formName').value);
  formData.append('email', this.contactForm.get('formEmail').value);
  formData.append('phone', this.contactForm.get('formPhone').value);
  formData.append('message', this.contactForm.get('formMessage').value);
  this.blogpostService.contactForm(formData).subscribe(
    data => {console.log(data)
      this.toastr.successToastr('Your contact information is saved Susseccfully!', 'Success!');
       setTimeout(() =>{
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }, 1000)
},
    error => {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(error.errorMessage);
      this.toastr.errorToastr('This is not good!', 'Oops!');
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    })}}
```

service .ts file:

```
   public contactForm(formData): Observable<any> {
    let myResponse = this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/send/mail', formData);
    // console.log(formData.get('name'))
    return myResponse;
  }
```

**UPDATE** index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const appConfig = require('./config/appConfig')
const fs = require('fs')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const globalErrorMiddleware = require ('./app/middlewares/appErrorHandler');
const routeLoggerMiddleware = require('./app/middlewares/routeLogger');
const logger = require('./app/libs/loggerLib');

//declaring an instance or creating an application instance
const app = express()

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json())    //bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'))

app.use(globalErrorMiddleware.globalErrorHandler);
app.use(routeLoggerMiddleware.logIp);

// Bootstrap models
let modelsPath = './app/models'
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file) {
    if (~file.indexOf('.js')) {
        console.log(file)
        require(modelsPath + '/' + file)
    }
  })
  // end Bootstrap models

// Bootstrap route
let routesPath = './app/routes'
fs.readdirSync(routesPath).forEach(function (file) {
    if (~file.indexOf('.js')) {
        console.log("including the following file");
        console.log(routesPath + '/' + file)
        let route = require(routesPath + '/' + file);
        route.setRouter(app);
    }
});// end bootstrap route

app.use(globalErrorMiddleware.globalNotFoundHandler);

//listening the server - creating a local server
const server = http.createServer(app)
// start listening to http server
console.log(appConfig)
server.listen(appConfig.port)
server.on('error', onError)
server.on('listening', onListening)
function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        logger.error(error.code + ' not equal listen', 'serverOnErrorHandler', 10)
        throw error
    }
    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            logger.error(error.code + ':elavated privileges required', 'serverOnErrorHandler', 10)
            process.exit(1)
            break
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            logger.error(error.code + ':port is already in use.', 'serverOnErrorHandler', 10)
            process.exit(1)
            break
        default:
            logger.error(error.code + ':some unknown error occured', 'serverOnErrorHandler', 10)
            throw error
    }
}   //end of On Error
function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address()
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
        ? 'pipe ' + addr
        : 'port ' + addr.port;
    ('Listening on ' + bind)
    logger.info('server listening on port' + addr.port, 'serverOnListeningHandler', 10)
    let db = mongoose.connect(appConfig.db.uri, { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })  //end of onListening}
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.log('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason)
    // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
})
// handling mongoose connection error
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('database connection error');
    console.log(err)
}); // end mongoose connection error
// handling mongoose success event
mongoose.connection.on('open', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("database error");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("database connection open success");
    }}); // end mongoose connection open handler
```

[image]

Comment: console log req object and tell output.

Comment: Also are you using bodyparser?

Comment: when I console log the whole object user it's coming as [object Object]. Yes I'm using body-parser

Comment: no its should display the whole object when you console.log(req) without string

Comment: sorry my bad i meant req. As for CORS you have allow all origins in headers. Have you done that?

Comment: req is also coming as [object Object]

Comment: try req.body now

Comment: same as [object Object]

Comment: this.blogpostService.contactForm(formData).subscribe( . Before passing formDatahere console log it before it and see

Comment: getting the values as expected. the values are passing all fine in the front-end till it goes to the node controller function

Comment: ok kindly attach the screenshot on the req.body result and also add code of your index file where you added body parser

Comment: updated! please check

Comment: dont include string with the object dude. Just console.log(req.body)

Comment: Updated! now it's coming as an empty object. Check out the image

Comment: Ok so for some obvious reasons, the formdata is not acccesible in the api hence an alternative approach would be to pass data as JSON rather than formdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing data in JSON rather than formdata.

```
  public contact() {
    let param =  {
       'name': this.contactForm.get('formName').value,
       'email': this.contactForm.get('formEmail').value,
       'phone': this.contactForm.get('formPhone').value,
       'message': this.contactForm.get('formMessage').value,
    }

    this.blogpostService.contactForm(param).subscribe(
      data => {console.log(data)
        this.toastr.successToastr('Your contact information is saved Susseccfully!', 'Success!');
         setTimeout(() =>{
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }, 1000)
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.errorMessage);
        this.toastr.errorToastr('This is not good!', 'Oops!');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      })
  }
```